# Closing an App programmatically, that was called programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I call an application (the same app, from which it is called) programmatically from inside the App.xaml.cs:

```
            var newProcess = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = "ASA-Videowand.exe",
                    WorkingDirectory = myPath,
                    Arguments = _maxScreen.ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                }
            };
            newProcess.Start();
```

Now I want to check the arguments at startup and when it is not what i want, close the app. I already tried it with an `Application.Current.Shutdown();`, but with no effect at all (not an error, nor an end of the process). Someone an idea what I can do?

Comment: Can't you just end the process? `newProcess.Kill()`?

Comment: How about `System.Environment.Exit(0);` in ASA-Videowand?

Comment: Mike Eason: I want to kill it from inside, not from another process.
Jens: Doesn't work either.
GrantWinney: Basically you're right and will do it this way in the end, but I wondered why it won't work.

Comment: where did you write Application.Current.Shutdown();

Comment: Ok, thats... embarrasing... it was written in the false context. *cough* Thanks Justin... :/